# How to pause specific HTML5 audio when playing HTML5video

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

Reference http://america.wtf/Shadex

The site has audio that auto plays. However there is a videos page. I want to have it so that when you play the videos it auto pauses the music

```html
<div id="videos" style="z-index:1" onClick="document.getElementById('sitemusic').pause();"><br />
<div align="center" id="videobox">Splash
<video style="z-index:-1;" width="400" controls>
  <source src="media/videos/splash.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="media/videos/splash.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</div>
</div>

<audio id="sitemusic" controls autoplay>
  <source src="media/turbo_grid.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="media/turbo_grid.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
  <script>
  var video = document.currentScript.parentElement;
  video.volume = 0.1;
  </script>
</audio>
```

Comment: have you looked at setting something on the event listener for the video element that responds to the onPlay to pause the audio?

Comment: Not sure how that would be done. Do you have example?

Answer (score 0):

see below for updated sample which will:

- Pause the audio when you play the video
- Play the audio when you pause the video

note the I removed the `onClick` from the video element, and also added an explicit `id` to the `<video>` element to make directly referencing it easier

```
<div id="videos" style="z-index:1"><br />
<div align="center" id="videobox">Splash
<video style="z-index:-1;" width="400" controls id="video">
    <source src="media/videos/splash.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="media/videos/splash.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</div>
</div>

<audio id="sitemusic" controls autoplay>
  <source src="media/turbo_grid.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="media/turbo_grid.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
  <script>
    var audio = document.currentScript.parentElement;
    audio.volume = 0.1;

    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    // this event listener reacts to "play" happening on video element and enacts pause on the audio element
    video.addEventListener('play', function (){document.getElementById("sitemusic").pause()},false);
    // this event listener reacts to "pause" happening on video element and enacts play on the audio element
    video.addEventListener('pause', function (){document.getElementById("sitemusic").play()},false);
  </script>
</audio>
```